# Elasticsearch aggregation by field name

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine two documents:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "abc",
        "categories": {
            "category-id-1": 1,
            "category-id-2": 50
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "def",
        "categories": {
            "category-id-1": 2
        }
    }
]
```

As you can see, each document can be associated with a number of categories, by setting a nested field into the `categories` field.

With this mapping, I should be able to request the documents from a defined category and to order them by the value set as value for this field.

My problem is that I now want to make an aggregation to count for each category the number of documents. That would give the following result for the dataset I provided:

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "categories" : {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "category-id-1",
                    "doc_count": 2
                },
                {
                    "key": "category-id-2",
                    "doc_count": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I can't find anything in the documentation to solve this problem. I'm completely new to ElasticSearch so I may be doing something wrong either on my documentation research or on my mapping choice.

**Is it possible to make this kind of aggregation with my mapping? I'm using ES 6.x**

*EDIT: Here is the mapping for the index:*

```
{
  "test1234": {
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "properties": {
          "categories": {
            "properties": {
              "category-id-1": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "category-id-2": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you post your mapping?

Comment: Hi, thank you for commenting, I added the mapping to the question.

Comment: so if I understand well you would like to retrieve not the aggregated values of key category-id-1 , but the number of docs which have the field category-id-1, right?

Comment: Exactly, without mentioning `category-id-1` nor `category-id-2` in my request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward solution is to use a new field that contains all the distinct categories of a document.

If we call this field `categories_list` here could be a solution :

Change the mapping to

```
{
  "test1234": {
    "mappings": {
      "_doc": {
        "properties": {
          "categories": {
            "properties": {
              "category-id-1": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "category-id-2": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "categories_list": {
             "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you need to modify your documents like this :

```
[
    {
        "_id": "abc",
        "categories": {
            "category-id-1": 1,
            "category-id-2": 50
        },
        "categories_list": ["category-id-1", "category-id-2"]
    },
    {
        "_id": "def",
        "categories": {
            "category-id-1": 2
        },
        "categories_list": ["category-id-1"]
    }
]
```

then your aggregation request should be

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "categories": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "categories_list",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and will return

```
"aggregations": {
    "categories": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "category-id-1",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "category-id-2",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```